# Performance, security and best practices between TextEdit.Text and TextEdit.EditValue

Tags: c#, text, devexpress, editor, text-editor

Currently I am using DX components, and whenever I use the *TextEdit* component I use to get its value by `EditValue`'s property.

However, lots of times I do face the famous `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"` error.

This, mostly being caused by the fact that the *TextEdit* is bound to a `String` property, and whenever I assign the `EditValue` property of the empty editor to model's property, this will pass `null`, causing further issues.

Yes, basically this is the main issue I face, and sometimes I am forced to use `Text` property of the editor instead of the above mentioned one.

What are the main risks of using one or the other, and what are some best practices?

Comment: Why not just change the model code in a way that it can handle null values? Imho you should always be prepared for null values when using `string`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit.Text.property), the Text property returns the text displayed in the editor.

The text displayed in the editor takes into account the [DisplayFormat](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItem.DisplayFormat.property), and can be modified using the [FormatEditValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItem.FormatEditValue.event) and [CustomEditValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseEdit.CustomDisplayText.event) events.

So, the EditValue and DisplayText properties return different values, although they are equal in many cases. There is no a best practice suggesting you which property to use. It all depends on whether your business logic require an actual value or a text the user sees on the screen.